# Parse - Resend Email Verification

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, email, parse-platform

So I want to be able to resend an email verification, based on the users inputted email address in a UITextField and build whether the email address has already been verified or not. Now I know I need to "resave" the email address for parse to send the email. However when I'm looking up in the database the email address it keeps saying it cannot find it and the email address is definitely there and not verified.

```
-(IBAction)emailVerification:(id)sender{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:self.email.text];
[query whereKey:@"emailVerified" equalTo:false];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!object) {
        NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");
        //Failed, incorrect email address
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Check your internet connection and/or the email address"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else {
        //found email address check verified
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved the object.");
        [query whereKey:@"emailVerified" equalTo:false];
        [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!object) {
                // The find succeeded.
                object[@"email"]=self.email.text;
                [object saveInBackground];

            }
            else {
                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Already Verified!"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        }];
    }


   }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access user information, you need to use the `PFUser` object defined in `Parse`.

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
```

`PFUser` has functions for getting the email address and for checking if the email has been verified.

What I want to know is how to resend the email verification? This is not a procedure defined in the `PFUser` object.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] If you just set again the user's email with the same email, Parse won't trigger the process which re-send the verification mail.
You must first set a fake email --> save --> set the correct email --> save.
Now Parse notices a actual change and do triggers the verification email process.

Answer (score 1):

Change the capitalization of the email.

```
BOOL upperCase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[currentUser.email characterAtIndex:0]];

if (upperCase) {
   [currentUser setEmail:[currentUser.email lowercaseString]];
}else {
   [currentUser setEmail:[currentUser.email capitalizedString]];
}
[currentUser saveEventually];
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely as a test: to have Parse.com send a new verificiation email to a user:

```
let email = PFUser.currentUser()?.email
PFUser.currentUser()?.email = "temp@temp.com"
PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
PFUser.currentUser()?.email = email
PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
```

This solution is brittle. In many ways.

1. If Parse.com fails after setting the temporarory email address but before resetting it to the correct email address then the account will be lost to the user when they next try to login.
2. If #1 happens, then you (and your Customer Service) won't know what the correct email address either.
3. If #1 happens, what happens to other users using this function? Can their account email field be temporarily set to "temp@temp.com"? Answer: no it can't. The saveInBackground() will fail and so no email change will happen and so no verification email will be sent.
4. If multiple users try to get a new verification email in the same time frame, what happens when a second account tries sets the email address field to "temp@temp.com" ? Based on #3 I would say #fail.
5. If Parse.com changes the implementation could the code generate two verification emails? One for each .saveInBackground(). Actually, Parse does send out an email for each saveInBackground.

I can't code for all these points but here's some ideas:

1. When saving "temp@temp.com" one could also save the user's entered email address in another field to be used by a recovery function. The recovery function could be manually started or run periodically to clean up after any "fails".
2. Rather than "temp@temp.com" use a randomly generated email address to mitigate clashers between users.

### Notes

1. Sending a new verification email voids the earlier email (i.e. the 'verify' hyperlink in the earlier email, when clicked, will tell the user that verification has failed).
2. If you skip the two lines that set and save the user's email to a temporary value then no verification email is sent by Parse.com.